# Graph only selected categories in Excel

Tags: excel, graph

I have an excel document (can change it to Numbers if helpful) in which I have swimming results in the following table:

```
Week | Swimmer | Event    | Time
-----+---------+----------+------
1    | James   | 50m Free | 40.0
1    | Mary    | 50m Free | 41.3
1    | Bob     | 50m Free | 40.5
1    | James   | 50m Back | 51.3
1    | Mary    | 50m Back | 56.7
1    | Bob     | 50m Fly  | 71.2
1    | Alex    | 50m Fly  | 73.1
2...etc
```

I'd like to be able to visualise the trend for each event for each swimmer. I only need to to see one graph at once. In my head, I'd like a drop down for swimmer, a drop down for event (even better would be a drop down of events only which the selected swimmer has results for). The part that I'm having difficulty with is selecting only the relevant data to show in the graph. For example, after selecting "James" and "50m Free" I only want to select those lines to graph, and nothing else. Is this possible? Ideally, not using VBA please. The data set is not complete, it gets added to every week.

I've tried a few things already but I'm coming unstuck when new results are added as they aren't included in the graph. I have tried creating a temporary table with just the results I want using the `filter` function, but it seems that Excel doesn't like to graph the spilled results of this method.

Any other ideas?